# memmem() STL way?

Tags: c++, stl

Is there an STL algorithm which can be used to search a sequence of bytes inside a buffer like memmem() does?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if this is good code, but the following works, using [`std::search`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/search/):

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string.h>
#include <algorithm>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *a = argv[0];
    char *a_end = a + strlen(a);
    char *match = "out";
    char *match_end = match+strlen(match); // If match contained nulls, you would have to know its length.

    char *res = std::search(a, a_end, match, match_end);

    printf("%p %p %p\n", a, a_end, res);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Old version did sizeof(match) which ONLY worked because match pointed at a 3 letter string, and it was tested on a 32 bit architecture.  strlen(match) is the right way to get that string length.  Another way would have been to use char match[] = "out" and then use sizeof(match).

Comment: For more efficiency, you might want to use this Boyer-Moore-Horspool though: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore%E2%80%93Horspool_algorithm

Answer (score 2):

`std::search` will find the first occurrence of one sequence inside another sequence.

Answer (score 0):

What about `find` and `substr`?

```
#include <string>
using std::string;
...
size_t found;

found = s.find("ab",4);
if (found != string::npos)
  finalString = s.substr(found); // get from "ab" to the end
```

Comment: If the binary string contains null bytes, it fails.

Comment: @Raindog according to my tests, wrong, std::string::find is binary safe. https://ideone.com/Ata5Yr

Answer (score -1):

Why not use strstr?

There is no algorithm implemented. You could implement your own predicate to be used in combination with std::find_if, but it is overengineering, IMO.

Comment: `strstr` would require you to zero-terminate the sequences, and wouldn't work if they can contain zeros. There is an algorithm: `std::search`.