# Search block of memory for 2 consecutive chars

Tags: c++, c

I got a block of memory where I need to search for 2 consecutive chars.

I can't use strstr since my block of memory might contain '\0', and memchr only search for a single char. Is there some function similar to strstr, that works for non null-terminated, or should I use memchr followed by a manual check of the next element. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want a C solution or a C++ solution ?

Comment: The GNU C library has a non-standard extension called `memmem` that does this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280553/memmem-stl-way

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to search in a BYTE array for a pattern?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7319391/how-to-search-in-a-byte-array-for-a-pattern) or [A pure bytes version of strstr?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992253/a-pure-bytes-version-of-strstr).

Comment: @PaulR Here at stackoverflow, they don't think there is a difference between c and c++.  I gave up trying to convince them a long time ago.

Answer (score 3):

```
for (p = memstart; p <= (memstart + memsize - stringsize); p++)
{
    if (memcmp(p, string, stringsize) == 0)
    return p; /* found */
}
return NULL; /* not found */
```

http://www.koders.com/c/fidD66F4C2F1935B0FF6158A83C4FBF134C4432F5CF.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The C++ way to do this would be:

```
char* result = std::search_n( mem, mem + size, 2, c );
```

Where `mem` is the start of your buffer, `size` is the size in bytes, and `c` is the character to search for.  search_n should return `mem + size` if no match is found.